# multiprocessing logger not working in subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-multiprocessing

I have two classes - `Coordinator` and `Worker`. The `Worker` class is a subclass of `multiprocessing.Process`. `Coordinator` instantiates a bunch of processes. When I try to log to stderr from the `Worker` process, it doesn't work but if I log from `Coordinator`, it does. Using `multiprocess.log_to_stderr()` in `Worker` class also works but customizing the formatter doesn't have any effect. Tried to read through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) here but it's not really clear what is wrong. Order of logging is not important.

Some pseudo code.

```
class Coordinator:
  def __init__(self):
    self.logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(processName)s | %(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s| %(message)s"
    )
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger.handlers.clear()
    self.logger.addHandler(handler)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    # forkserver is used because of other dependencies
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("forkserver", force=True)

  def execute_something(self):
    p = Worker()
    self.logger.info("This gets printed.")
    p.start()
    p.join()

def main():
  c = Coordinator()
  c.execute_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



class Worker(Process):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(daemon=True)
    self.logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
      "%(processName)s | %(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s| %(message)s"
    )
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger.handlers.clear()
    self.logger.addHandler(handler)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  def run(self):
    self.logger.info("This doesn't get printed.")
```

Comment: A cursory glance at the issue showed that "forkserver" definitely has something to do with it.

Comment: A workaround would be to set up the logging for the Worker inside its `run()` method.